# sh: webpack: command not found error when upload my hello world reactjs project on beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, package.json

I am having problem deploying my hello world reactjs application on beanstalk.
I do this when I want to run it manually:
1) npm start

and then the project is built and copied on dist folder and it works.
Here is my package.json script section:

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "npm run build && node server",
"build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack -d && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/index.html\" /F /Y"
}
```

When I deploy the project on beanstalk I get the following error:

```
sh: webpack: command not found
```

Also a completed stack of error is added at the end of this post for more details.
I searched a lot and it seems to be the problem of global set up of webpack so I even used preinstall to set up webpack globally but no result. Any idea or any help is appreciated

Full stack error:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
 -------------------------------------
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build script 'webpack -d && 
 xcopy "src/index.html" "dist/index.html" /F /Y'.
 npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
 installed.
  npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics 
  package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     webpack -d && xcopy "src/index.html" "dist/index.html" /F /Y
 npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
 with:
  npm ERR!     npm bugs reactjs-basics
  npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs-basics
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log

   npm ERR! Linux 4.9.32-15.41.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.1-linux-
  x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.1-linux-
 x64/bin/npm" "start"
 npm ERR! node v6.11.1
 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start: `npm run build && node server`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start script 'npm run build && 
 node server'.
 npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm 
 installed.
 npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the reactjs-basics 
  package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     npm run build && node server
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
   with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs reactjs-basics
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls reactjs-basics
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
     npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log

     > reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start /var/app/current
     > npm run build && node server


        > reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build /var/app/current
          > webpack -d && xcopy "src/index.html" "dist/index.html" /F /Y

          sh: webpack: command not found
```

Update:  My dependencies and dev dependencies are as follow:

```
  "dependencies": {
   "react": "^15.4.1",
   "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.2.1"
    },
   "devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^6.20.0",
   "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
   "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
     "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
     "chai": "^3.5.0",
     "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
     "gulp": "^3.9.1",
     "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.4.0",
     "gulp-open": "^2.0.0",
     "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
     "webpack": "^1.14.0",
     "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
      "react-scripts": "0.2.1"
     }
```

Comment: it looks like you don't have `webpack` installed. is it on `devDependencies`? Do you install `devDependencies` in `production`? then, you don't need to point to the path if you run the script through npm, change `node_modules/.bin/webpack` to `webpack`

Comment: Thanks @Hitmands actually I have webpack in devdependencies bit not on dependencies itself. I tried it without node_modules/.bin/ and it did not work as well. DO you think I should add webpack  in dependencies as well?

Comment: I also updated my post with dependencies and dev-dependencies of my package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

The problem is my script file so instead of

```
"build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack -d && xcopy \"src/index.html\" \"dist/index.html\" /F /Y"
```

should be

```
webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html
```